# Dynamically changing the attribute value in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Input:-

```
<header>
    <apply_to>Header Level 1</apply_to>
    <apply_to>Header Level 2</apply_to>
    <apply_to>Header Level 3</apply_to>
</header>
```

My XSLT:-

```
<xsl:template match="apply_to">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="text() = 'Header Level 1'">
        <xsl:attribute name="Header1">
          <xsl:value-of select="'Yes'"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:when>

      <xsl:when test="text() = 'Header Level 2'">
        <xsl:attribute name="Header2">
          <xsl:value-of select="'Yes'"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:when>

      <xsl:when test="text() = 'Header Level 3'">
        <xsl:attribute name="Header3">
          <xsl:value-of select="'Yes'"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:when>

      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:if test="text() = 'Header Level 2' or 'Header Level 3'">
          <xsl:attribute name="styleHeader1">
            <xsl:value-of select="'No'"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="text() = 'Page Header' or 'Header Level 3'">
          <xsl:attribute name="styleHeader2">
            <xsl:value-of select="'No'"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="text() = 'Header Level 2' or 'Page Header'">
          <xsl:attribute name="styleHeader3">
            <xsl:value-of select="'No'"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:otherwise>
```

Output:-

```
<Headers Header1="Yes" Header2="Yes" Header3="Yes" colorOptions="option2"/>
```

Now my requirement is that I need to replace the attribute value to "No" in the output if the input element is not present.
eg:`<apply_to>Header Level 1</apply_to>` is not present in the input file. In that case I need to replace that value to "No" in the output.

```
<Headers Header1="No" Header2="Yes" Header3="Yes" colorOptions="option2"/>
```

How can i acheive this? Suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
<xsl:template match="header">
    <Headers>
        <xsl:attribute name="Header1">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="apply_to[.='Header Level 1']">Yes</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>No</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <!-- repeat for the other header levels -->
    </Headers>
</xsl:template>
```

---

**Note**:

I don't think this does what you think it does:

```
<xsl:if test="text() = 'Header Level 2' or 'Header Level 3'">
```

Comment: Hi, there are three differen attributes in the output. apply_to element coming thrice, so it is a for each loop, And your logic overrides attribute values.

Comment: <Headers Header1="No" Header2="No" Header3="Yes" />. In my input Header Level 2 is present, But as per your logic I got the output Header2 = "No". Because it overrides..

Comment: I said "repeat for the other header levels". There is no "for each loop" here, because you want three attributes every time. -- I didn't understand the part about overriding attribute values.